# how to use boost in linux

Tags: c++, linux, boost

I'm trying to use the shared pointer class(?) from boost. I have downloded boost and extracted it to a subfolder(boost) in my source folder (src). I have then added a line:

```
#include "boost/shared_ptr.hpp"
```

When I try to compile, I get an error:

> error: boost/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.hpp: No such file or directory

What do I have to add for the program to compile?

I'm working on a scientific linux machine without root privliges

Answer (score 12):

You will need to, with `g++`, add the directory as a compile option like `g++ -I./boost ...` or basically add as a command line option `-I` directly followed without a space by the relative or absolute path where you have installed your boost library.  Keep in mind also for future reference that some elements of boost, like the threading library also require some libraries to be linked against, and you will have to also include those file-paths at compile time using the `-L` option ... that isn't the case with `boost::shared_ptr`, but just giving you a head's up.

Comment: This didn't work since the error is originated by a file which is called from shared_ptr.hpp. I have replaced this with -I./ and it worked

Comment: Ah, okay, but again, the problem is that the compiler didn't know where to access the correct files ... for instance, in the shared_ptr.hpp file, the `#include` preprocessor directive is most likely using the `<...>` syntax rather than using quotes, which means it will only find the file in a searchable directory.  If the current directory is not a searchable directory using the angle-brackets syntax, it won't find the file.  If you're using the `<...>` syntax, you'll have to use the `-I` option to include any paths that need to be searched, or add those paths to your environment variables.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming you have installed boost to some subdirectory of your home directory, you'll need to do one of these to specify where the compiler should look for the boost header files:

- add a -I flag to the compiler command line ([GCC docs](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Directory-Options.html#Directory-Options))
- set the `CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH` environment variable ([GCC docs](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Environment-Variables.html#Environment-Variables))

Answer (score 2):

You can add gcc -I option. [Documentation](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Directory-Options.html#Directory-Options).